# What does the phrase "get down low" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "get down low" mean in football (soccer) context?

30 min
SAVE! Man Utd are looking so dangerous on the break. This time it's Rooney who leads the charge, picking out Mata on the edge of the box. The Spaniard takes a touch before hitting a powerful strike towards goal but Adrian **gets down low** to push the shot away. The visitors desperately want that second goal

Comment: It's not really a set phrase. He literally moved/stretched lower down, closer to the ground.

Comment: I know nothing about football, but from the context, it's clear that the goalie got closer to the ground and kept the ball out of the goal.